# Avast Safezone Browser update

Tags: browser, updates

I am using Avast Endpoint protection suite ver 8.0.1607. I use Safezone for my banking. While using the Safezone browser this morning I got a message saying something like "It looks like your browser is not the latest - consider updating". I could not find any place where I could update the browser. The browser "about" menu option does not seem to provide this facility, nor does there seem to be a download/upgade link anywhere. I rang Avast and waited on their support line for 40 minutes listening to Muzak then hung up. Do I need to update the browser? If so, how do I update it?

Comment: Have you considered posting this answer in the Avast forum?

Comment: @BJD You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection this must be done under the original user account. It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: I'm don't know for sure, but since Avast is based upon Chrome maybe it is using the installed Chrome on your machine. I would try checking that your Chrome version is current.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible social engineering phishing advertisement campaign.  It may not even related to ANY browser you use.

It is carefully crafted malvertisement to tricks the user to click on "update" button to download malware.